# Are arcades considered haram?

Tags: halal-haram, money, bidah

Asalam wa alakum, well my close friend is celebrating her birthday party, and we are going to the arcades(you know where you pay to play games, then you win a prize and there is also bowling there) so I was going but then i thought that i might be haram. Her birthday is the 22.03.14 so please inform me as soon as you can, thank you.

Comment: Walaykum salam wa-rahmutAllah wa-barakatuhu. Excellent question! Ask yourself,  why would it be haram?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but maybe it is considered as wasting money? (That's just a rough guess)

Comment: Is there an analogy you could draw then? Where've you looked?

Answer (score 2):

alakum salam.

Going to arcades isn't haraam as it doesn't fall under any general prohibitions of Islam.

Some have said that if the game involves doing haraam things, it would be haraam.  But again, it's a bit vague and games aren't real.  Allaho Alim.

Answer (score 1):

It is gambling
Abu’l-Baqa’ al-Hanafi said: Any game in which it is stipulated that the winner will take something from the loser comes under the heading of gambling.

End quote from al-Kulliyyaat (p. 702)

“O you who believe! Eat not up your property among yourselves unjustly except it be a trade amongst you, by mutual consent”

[an-Nisa’ 4:29].

Al-Baghawi said in his tafseer of this verse: “O you who believe, do not consume one another´s property by unjust means” i.e., harâm means, that is, through riba, gambling, plundering, stealing, treachery and so on.

“O you who believe! Intoxicants (all kinds of alcoholic drinks), and gambling, and Al Ansaab (stone altars for sacrifices to idols, etc.), and Al Azlaam (arrows for seeking luck or decision) are an abomination of Shaytaan’s (Satan’s) handiwork. So avoid (strictly all) that (abomination) in order that you may be successful.

Answer (score -4):

Arcades are haram. They are placed under gambling and this is considered wrong in Islam.

For more information read: http://islamqa.info/en/194873

Comment: The tickets are extra for fun, the prizes are usually worth nothing (toys). I think the person who answered didn't understand what was going on.

Comment: Please refrain from posting link-only answers: the URLs may become inaccessible which renders the answer useless for future users.